# Unable to display website on chrome when ran the program

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I had recently started learning automation with python using selenium. I had installed chromedriver but when i run the code chrome displays no output. My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("www.wikipedia.com")
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWpSO.png)

Output :

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/untitled/1.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver.get("www.wikipedia.com")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.96)
```

Please help as I'm unable to proceed.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

URL should contain [scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes). Simply replace

```
"www.wikipedia.com"
```

with

```
"https://www.wikipedia.com"
```